# English Articles: Perilla oil is an/the edible vegetable oil derived from perilla seeds

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

This is a sentence from Wikipedia.

> Perilla oil is an edible vegetable oil derived from perilla seeds.

I don't understand why it is *an edible vegetable oil*. We can only have one oil from perilla, i.e., perilla oil. So, it should be *the edible vegetable oil*, not *an edible vegetable oil*.

If the latter part *derived from perilla seeds* of the sentence is removed, it makes sense. We say *Perilla oil is an edible vegetable oil*. There are many edible vegetable oils, and perilla oil is one of them.

However, things change after adding the latter part. And the noun *oil* should follow the definite article *the* since we can only have one oil from perilla.

Any explanation to it is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your natural sense is correct. There is a subtlety.

If we ask the question: What edible oil is derived from perilla seeds?

> Perilla oil is the edible vegetable oil derived from perilla seeds

would be a good answer.

However, wikipedia is answering the request: Tell me about Perilla oil.

> Perilla oil is an edible vegetable oil [which is] derived from perilla seeds.

gives two separate facts about perilla oil.

> Perilla oil is an edible vegetable oil.

and

> Perilla oil is derived from perilla seeds.